# Is restful_authentication ever going to work for rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I like the simplicity of restful_authentication (as a newbie), was hoping it would work in rails 3.0.3 but when i ran bundle install it said it doesn't work for this version of rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People use [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) these days if they want to work with Rails 3. It is much easier, simpler and does not pollute your code. Is there any specific reason why you would want to use restful_auth?

Comment: seems so much simpler that's all, I just need a simple login not 3rd part integration etc.

Comment: I would say restful_auth is messy.

Comment: Someone might want to use it if they are upgrading an old app that uses it, rather than switch it out.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use gem "rails3-restful-authentication" with rails 3 support. 
just add

gem "rails3-restful-authentication", "~> 3.0.1"

in application Gemfile and it will support for rails 3 also.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it to work, at least partially, I have got it to work on everything except my delete method.  To do it there is a fork by Satish made for the Rails 3 release canidates, however I have figured out that it requires some configuration, but is possible.  You can find out more on http://vinsol.com/blog/2010/04/23/upgrading-restful-authentication-plugin-for-rails-3. I don't remember how I initially got it set up, or I would help more.  But, yes, it is supported, however, it is more as a help to get Rails 2 apps up to Rails 3 without having to rip apart the app too much.